# Copy/Paste cells & value

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I want to copy/paste all worksheet inlcuding the values/formula in the cells to another new workbook.

This code just copy the first ws, but not all other. How can I make sure, that all ws are gettin copied and pasted without writing all the names from the ws in the vba-code?

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
ws.Range("A1:G10").Copy
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If you wish to copy all the worksheets with all the data and all the formulas and all the formatting to a new workbook, why not **save the old workbook under a new name** ??

Comment: Yeah, but thats not an Option, because it isn't me using this Excel-woorkbook later and it should do this, because the user won't do it, so I make it sure with the vba code it happens

Comment: @Nicola

The code is almost working, but the Debugger has a Problem with the column: "workbook.Sheets(index)....."

error 9, so I tried this with the Name of the wb (test)
workbook.Sheets(test)...

but it didnt work

Comment: My Questions are:

1.How can I name the new workbook, example: The old one is timetable.xlsm

The new pasted one should be named as timetable_v2.xlsm


2.and with which command can be the names of the worksheet be retained in the pasted file?


3.I also get this Debugger error 9:

WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete


What should I replace or change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i assume you will be saving the second workbook for it to be named? therefore just add your path below where you want to save it, also it now retains the sheet names.
I'm not sure why you are getting a debugger error its working fine for me, try this code and see if you still get it?

```
Sub newworkbook()
Dim WBN As workbook, WBC As workbook, WB As workbook
Dim WS As String
Dim SHT As Worksheet

Set WBN = Workbooks.Add

For Each WB In Application.Workbooks

If WB.Name <> WBN.Name Then
For Each SHT In WB.Worksheets
    SHT.Copy After:=WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count)
    WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count).Name = (SHT.Name) & " "
Next SHT
End If
Next WB
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete
WBN.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\YOURPATH\timetable_v2.xls" 'change path to whatever
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the Problem with the error 9 still exist, so it won't be named the as I wanted to, but you help me a lot thanks

Comment: I just deleted `WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete
`
And it works fine

Comment: Great, glad you got there!

Comment: When the wb is pasted, there is also a "sheet1" ws in the new v2 wb, but I dont want that. How can I get rid of the useless sheet1 from copy/paste?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim aSheet As Worksheet
    Dim workbook As workbook
    Dim index As Integer

    Set workbook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    For Each aSheet In Worksheets

        aSheet.Range("A1:G10").Copy

        workbook.Sheets(index).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

        index = index + 1

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next aSheet


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look for you, this seems to do the job:

credit: [get digital help](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/10/02/copy-each-sheet-in-active-workbook-to-new-workbooks/)

```
Dim WBN As Workbook, WBC As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Dim WS As String
Dim SHT As Worksheet

Set WBN = Workbooks.Add
For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
If WB.Name <> WBN.Name Then
    For Each SHT In WB.Worksheets
        SHT.Copy After:=WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count)
        WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count).Name = Left(WB.Name, 30 - Len(SHT.Name)) & "-" & SHT.Name
    Next SHT
End If
Next WB
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete
WBN.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete`

And it works fine

The new workbook is saved as an .xlsx file, but of course I Need it as an .xlsm file....when I just added it into the path, it doesnt work

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "U:\Excel\timetable_v2.xlsm"
```